# How to add multiple certificates to npm's .npmrc cafile config?

Tags: windows, npm, cygwin, npm-install, npm-login

(I'm on Windows using cygwin for development and trying to set up my dev env, where other devs are on Unix, I've tried installing ubuntu terminal but the organisation's rules disallow using the windows store and installing it seperate fails for seemingly the same reason.)

I'm trying to add two different .pem certificates provided by my organization to npm's cafile config in .npmrc, but it will only accept a single file, I've tried `cat`-ing them together but it seemingly only accepts the first certificate in the file. Is there a way of adding more certificates? I have tried using the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS variable but it gives an error `library:fopen:No such process` which is apparently a bug on their end.

So I'm at a loss, how can I add more than one cert?

Answer (score 0):

Append It's content to the first `.pem` file wich addressed in `.npmrc` file.

If getting this error: `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` run this command: `git config --global http.sslCAInfo <PATH TO .pem FILE>`